# Conditional Formatting not working as expected when I remove absolute references from rule

Tags: excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am using Excel 2016 & Windows 10...

I am having trouble getting a simple conditional formatting rule to work - I am sure I am doing something daft but I cannot seem to fix it...

When the rule is: =SUM($D$15:$D$19)<>0 and applied to this range: =$C$14:$D$19 it works as expected.

When I remove the absolute references from the second row number: =SUM($D$15:$D19)<>0 it works as expected.

When I remove the absolute reference from the first row number: =SUM($D15:$D19)<>0 it only applies the conditional formatting to the range: =$C$14:$D$**17** not =$C$14:$D$**19**

I have removed all other conditional formatting rules from the sheet - same result.

I have replicated in a brand new workbook, in a new instance of Excel - same result.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is expected behavior. With an absolute/relative reference in the formula, you define which range is used in the calculations relative to the `applies to` specified range.
I.e. if you specify an absolute reference, then it will be used for the whole `applies to` range,

if you specify `SUM($D$15:$D19)` for `applies to` range `$C$14:$D$19`, then cell `C14` will use the formula `SUM($D$15:$D15)`, cell `C15` will use `SUM($D$15:$D16)` etc.

However, if you specify `SUM($D15:$D$19)`, then in cell `C14` the formula `SUM($D$15:$D$19)` will be used, in cell `C15` - `SUM($D16:$D$19)`, in cell `C16` - `SUM($D17:$D$19)` etc.

Comment: Thank you!  That's so obvious (now that it's been pointed out!!) - a fresh pair of eyes always helps!